# Make jQuery datepicker pop upwards

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

My jQuery UI datepickers pop downwards and this makes them disappear across the bottom of the screen sometimes. I'd like to make them pop upwards instead.

I came across this solution
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerPosition.html 
and so I've added in this code at the very end after all my other JS has been loaded but I'm getting an Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datePicker'.

Any idea what's wrong, or is there another way?

```
<!--Make the datepicker pop upwards-->
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function()
{
    $('.date-pick')
            .datepicker({createButton:false})
            .bind('click',
                    function()
                    {
                            $(this).dpDisplay();
                            this.blur();
                            return false;
                    }
            );
    $('#bl').dpSetPosition($.dpConst.POS_BOTTOM, $.dpConst.POS_LEFT);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery ui datepicker is lowercase, so change

```
.datePicker({createButton: false})
```

to

```
.datepicker({createButton: false})
```

source reference: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Edit: It also looks like the datepicker in your example is either a different datepicker or the one that was created prior to its induction into jquery-ui, which is why there is a discrepancy.

Comment: Thanks. But now I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'POS_BOTTOM' of undefined "

Comment: Yeah it looks like the jquery-ui datepicker doesn't have a dpConst argument, so you might have to switch from using a jquery-ui datepicker to using the jquery datePicker function that is provided in your example site.  If all you want to do is relocate the datepicker you can do it with CSS though

    `.ui-datepicker { 
       margin-left: -100px; margin-top:-100px;
    }` or however much you need it moved over and/or up.

Comment: Cheers, that worked a treat. I didn't realize it was that simple!! Thanks!!